# url parse - route not found

Tags: php, parsing, url, routes

I have designed a website, it was working fine, but lately I modified the links for SEO purposes. I just replaced `_` with `-`. Now I am getting a route not found error.

This is the matching array

```
$routes = array(
    array('url' => '/^products\/(?P<cat>\w+)$/', 'controller' => 'products', 'view' => 'products_list')
);
```

The link goes like this

> http://localhost/product/sample-page

When I remove `-` or replace it with `_` it works.

Comment: I bet `\w` does not match "-".

Comment: \w is for matching digits, word characters (letters, digits, and underscores), and whitespace (spaces, tabs, and line breaks).

Comment: @JeremySpouken AFAIK, `\w` does _not_ match spaces, tabs, or line breaks.

Comment: Sorry rusty a bit, must be matched with \s to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex from the shorthand character class `\w`, which matches letters, digits, and underscore, to a more explicit one to match upper and lower case letters, digits, `_`, and `-`.

```
$routes = array(
    array('url' => '/^products\/(?P<cat>[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$/', 'controller' => 'products', 'view' => 'products_list')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also leave the \w in there, but add - explicitly, i.e.

```
$routes = array(
array('url' => '/^products\/(?P<cat>[\w\-]+)$/', 'controller' => 'products', 'view' => 'products_list')
```

);

Answer (score 0):

You can check here an example:

http://rubular.com/r/czUkSgbYjs

And you can play with different regex.

Answer (score 0):

Hi friends I found another method to parse url. Using this you could have ".html" at the end of url for Search engine friendly.

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

url parse code

```
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
    $url = str_replace(".html", "", $url);
    $url = str_replace("-", "_", $url);
        //you could use rtrim(); but I had some trouble when the url had the "t" as the ending character.
    //$url = rtrim($url, '.html');
    $url = explode('/', $url);
```